# Where are the form names stored for WPForms?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, wpforms

I'm trying to recreate the WPForms Entries section for a customer portal. I can find all of the entries and related information in the phpMyAdmin database, except for the form names. The closest I have been able to find is the form_id, which is great for relational linking, but without the form name being found I would need to manually place these in the code and link them with the ID. I'd prefer to just grab it from the DB in case others are added.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wpforms create a new post type **wpforms**, and you can find the all information in **wp_posts** table. You can locate title under the **post_title** column in **wp_posts** table.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sukhjinder! this was driving me bonkers